# Visual Studio 2013 пропало отображение референсов у классов и методов

Tags: visual-studio, configuration

Всем привет!

В Visual Studio 2013 у меня перестали отображаться референсы в классах и методах... =\

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гуглил, искал, пытался даже сделать [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17848184/5788855), но в настройках студии нет параметров ни `CodeLens` ни `Code Information Indicators`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где-то натыкался на информацию, о том, что это из-за отсутствия какого пакета от TFS, а также писали, что данный функционал убрали вообще разработчики в 2013 студии

**Собственно вопросы**

> Как все-таки вернуть отображение референсов?
>   Нет ли такой возможности у Resharper?

Comment: У решапрера есть find usages в выпадающем меню при правом клике.

Comment: @AndrewB, да, знаю - это неудобно

Comment: У меня появился code lens в VS 2015 Community дома, после того как установил SSDT (инструменты для sql server). Попробуйте об этом для 2013 погуглить.

Comment: @AndrewB, установил, к сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Был такой случай после того, как я поставил Resharper.
Помогло восстановление VS.

Comment: Действительно решается восстановлением